# PHP process file before uploading it to amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, file-upload, process

I need to get histogram of the image before uploading it to Amazon s3. histogram works fine uplading works fine but I can not process the image file before uploading.

I don't want to save the image to local harddisk and process it and delete the local file upload to s3.

do you know any solution besides that? My histogram maker function is working with local files.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When uploading a file to PHP, it will always be saved to disk before your PHP script starts executing (see `upload_tmp_dir` in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)). The closest thing to having an in-memory upload would be to use a ramdisk for that temporary upload location.

Instead of uploading the file trough PHP, you could [upload it directly to S3 from the client's browser](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) but I don't really see how that would benefit you, since you will need to download it to your server at some point to do the histogram processing.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can send a file object or something like that by using a PUT method. And server-side you need process "php:/input" to read and write to file. Example code:

```
<?php 
 $handle= fopen("php://input", "r");
 $fileToWrite = fopen('test.txt','w');
  while ($data = fread($handle, 1024))
        fwrite($fileToWrite ,$data);
 fclose($handle);
 fclose($fileToWrite);
?>
```

---

This code works perfect with apache-windows (I think the same result with linux), but does not work for the others web-sever because the  server always buffer the client request before send to PHP-backend (I've tested with nginx, lighttpd) for better perfomance

---

2, Use websocket and FileReader !

I think This is the good choice, with websocket the problem is resolved. But there is the new problem if you want to dev a PHP-websocket-server. You shoud use node.js for websocket.
Good luck :)